# How to Stop OWL Carousel YouTube Video when Clicking Navigation Dot(s)

Tags: jquery

I have spent a lot of time getting the OWL carousel to work as desired on the website below. The carousel currently only contains embedded YouTube videos but will also contain some  files as well.

I have the carousel pausing on mouseover and it works great. Issue I have is that when someone starts a video, and then clicks a dot to go to another item, the video (audio) keeps playing.

I may be splitting hairs but if there is a simple way to stop the video / audio of any (and all) items in the carousel I sure would appreciate knowing how.

[peter.certifiedtransmission.com](http://peter.certifiedtransmission.com)

Comment: It's been awhile, but you need to dig into the youtube player API. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249948/youtube-api-playvideo-pausevideo-and-stopvideo-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OWL Carousel 2.3.4:

https://jsfiddle.net/iamrobert/p6y87hs0/12/

Use [onTranslate](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html) event/callback:

```
    onTranslate: function(event) {
    var currentSlide, player, command;

    currentSlide = $('.owl-item.active');

    player = currentSlide.find(".flex-video iframe").get(0);

    command = {
        "event": "command",
        "func": "pauseVideo"
    };

    if (player != undefined) {
        player.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify(command), "*");

    }

}
```

This example uses pause - however to stop the Video change:

"func": "pauseVideo" to "func": "stopVideo"

Also your youtube iframe video must include **?enablejsapi=1**

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="flex-video">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G1lq40tR72Q?enablejsapi=1" width="560" allowfullscreen frameborder="0" height="315"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Credit to: https://michaelsmyth.co.uk/pausing-youtube-vimeo-videos-postmessage/