# OwlCarousel2 pause embedded video after slide change

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have an Owl Carousel 2 with Vimeo and YouTube embed in some slides. I am trying to pause the video after slide change, but without success.

After some search, I've found that to pause an YouTube video I need to use API... I'm thinking in save the iframe in a variable, after change I delete the src from the slide and when I go back I put the iframe src again... is it possible? Or with another way?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's my solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55757465/1729791